# Office 365 - How do I set Allow Access Requests to Owners Group using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I could see RequestAccessEmail property available in CSOM for setting the email.. but how do I set this property to Owners Group. I could not see any property related to this even on Client.Group class.

Does CSOM way behind to expose this property?
Are there any alternatives to set this property via code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set `SetUseAccessRequestDefaultAndUpdate` to `$true`. This is a boolean property of the web object.

This site shows how it can be done in PowerShell / PnP:

[SharePoint Online: Configure Access Request Email Settings using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/sharepoint-online-access-request-email-settings-powershell.html)